Differential equations which cannot be solved by substituion in Sympy
These 2 differential equations taken from the book Advanced Mathematics by Mr. Spiegel, cannot be solved by Sympy. I have checked the documentation of Sympy on solving ODEs a lot. These equations can be solved by substituing y'= p and then sperating variables in p and y:


I am trying to solve various kinds of ODEs using sympy and have been able to get around some issues using hints, but I haven't been able to solve this one.
Trying to solve some ODEs using Sympy but could not do it
import sympy as sp
#p = sp.Symbol('p')
y = sp.Function('y')(x)
#p = sp.Function('p')
#p = sp.diff(y,x)
diff_eqn = sp.Eq(1+y*sp.diff(y,x,x)+sp.diff(y,x)**2,0)
diff_eqn
#Since x is not there in the equation we substitute y' = p
sp.dsolve(diff_eqn, y)#.subs(p,y.diff(x)).simplify()

Also I observe that I am not able to solve non homogenous linear equations, in general, in sympy (which have an RHS ne 0)
from sympy import dsolve, Function, Derivative, log, sin 
from sympy.abc import x 
f = Function('f') eq = Derivative(f(x), x, x) + 4*f(x) -8*sin(2*x) 
dsolve(eq, f(x),hint='nth_linear_euler_eq_nonhomogeneous_undetermined_coefficients').expand()

We should be able to solve this Euler ODE using this hint. I am getting the error:
ValueError: ODE 4*f(x) - 8*sin(2*x) + Derivative(f(x), (x, 2)) 
does not match hint 
nth_linear_euler_eq_nonhomogeneous_undetermined_coefficients


(1) Please share the code you have tried. (2) Please edit the equations to not use LaTeX, which doesn't get formatted on this site. Regular text will be easier to read.

from sympy import dsolve, Function, Derivative, log, sin from sympy.abc import x f = Function('f') eq = Derivative(f(x), x, x) + 4*f(x) - 8*sin(2*x) dsolve(eq, f(x),hint='nth_linear_euler_eq_nonhomogeneous_undetermined_coefficients').expand()
We should be able to solve this Euler ODE using this hint.........
